# C++ pass empty vector of structs to a function

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to pass an empty vector of structures to a function which will read from a file and it will return the number of records read -- it will be an integer.

I initialize the vector of structures in main and when I attempt to pass it to the function as I would regularly do it:

```
int read_records(vector<player> player_info)
```

It gives me a "player is undefined" error. I have found a way to go around it as you will see in my code below but logic leads me to believe that there should be a way to pass the empty vector without having to fill in the first subscript.

The code is below. Please note that the read function is not yet complete as I am still wondering about the vector of structs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

//function prototypes
int read_records(struct player* player_info);

/*
* Define a struct called player that will consist
* of the variables that are needed to read in each
* record for the players. 2 strings for the first
* and last names and 1 integer to hold the statistics
*/
struct player
{
    string first;
    string last;
    int stats;
};

int main(void)
{
    int sort_by, records_read;

    vector<player> player_info(1);
    player * point = &player_info[0];


    cout << "Welcome to Baseball player statistics program!" << endl;
    cout << "How should the information be sorted?" << endl;
    cout << "Enter 1 for First Name" << endl;
    cout << "Enter 2 for Last Name" << endl;
    cout << "Enter 3 for Points" << endl;
    cout << "Enter your selection: ";
    cin >> sort_by;

    //read the records into the array
    records_read = read_records(point);


    system("Pause");

    return 0;
}
int read_records(struct player* player_info)
{
    //declare the inputstream
    ifstream inputfile;

    //open the file
    inputfile.open("points.txt");

    //handle problem if the file fails to open for reading
    if (inputfile.fail())
    {
        cout << "The player file has failed to open!" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The player file has been read successfully!" << endl;
    }

    return 5;

}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that fails?  Otherwise, we have to guess what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @saulspatz: No, it's perfectly clear. If you don't know the answer, simply move on to another question. :)

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit It's not perfectly clear to me, and I was asking the OP not you.

Comment: @saulspatz: I see from your profile that you are a Python contributor, and have no evident C++ experience. Perhaps that's why it's not clear to you. Regardless, this question requires no further editing. And I can reply to whatever comment I like, thank you very much.

Comment: No, I have lots of C++ experience.  Of course, you can reply to any comment you like.  You could even do it mannerly, but I guess that's beyond you.

Comment: Thank you for the help guys, Xiaotian Pei's answer below solved everything, I have the function prototype above the struct definition so the problem gets to be that I am asking for something that is not defined. Silly mistake!

Comment: @saulspatz: I see that interacting with you is not going to be constructive. I shall therefore cease.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define the type `player` *before* you attempt to declare functions that need to know about that type.

```
struct player
{
    string first;
    string last;
    int stats;
};

int read_records(vector<player> player_info);
```

Your workaround was successful because naming `player` in `struct player*` acts as a [forward] declaration, in a way that naming it in `vector<player>` does not. (The whys and wherefores of this are too broad for this answer and are covered elsewhere on SO and in your C++ book.)

As an aside, I doubt you want to take that vector by value.

Comment: I thought since I declare a vector of structs it is enough for the compiler to pickup the custom type. 

Also when you pass a vector, I thought it is never passed by value because it simply passes the pointer to the memory location. The only way to pass by "value" is const.

Comment: @AlexTop: The compiler can't read your mind. It doesn't know that `vector<player>` is "a vector of structs" (actually, C++ doesn't have structures; only classes) until it knows what `player` is.

Comment: _"I thought it is never passed by value because it simply passes the pointer to the memory location"_ Where did you hear that?

Comment: _"The only way to pass by 'value' is const."_ Total nonsense. Constness has nothing at all to do with it.

Comment: My apologies, I was passing it by value I was mistaken that you can only pass it as a pointer. I do understand what constness means when it is applied to structures like that, it means that their content cannot change. Thank you very much for all the help! All of the information has been great! I am pretty sure I will not be making these 2 mistakes again.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put `struct player` definition before `int read_records(vector<player> player_info)`.

Comment: Thank you! What a stupid mistake, I guess the preprocessor was kicking back because I was asking for something that was not defined!

Thank you SO MUCH!